# safari IndexOutOfRangeException

Tags: asp.net, safari, infragistics, webcombo

I'm using Infragistics controls in my web application(ASP.net)... and I'm using Ultra web grid in that too.... my application works well in IE and Mozilla . but in safari I'm getting the following error: (which is very vague and fuzzy) ... What's this error?
Does it have to do with compatibility problem? how to resolve this?

**Index was outside the bounds of the array.**

```
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web *request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 
Exception Details: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
Source Error: 
An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
Stack Trace: 
[IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.]
   Infragistics.WebUI.WebCombo.WebCombo.LoadPostData(String postDataKey, NameValueCollection values) +611
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessPostData(NameValueCollection postData, Boolean fBeforeLoad) +611
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2877
Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.3053; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.3053*
```

Answer (score 0):

Very likely it's a browser compatibility issue, I suggest you contact Infragistics directly and ask them if their components are supported in Safari. If they are then you should report this issue to them as a bug.

Comment: ok thats fine... hey i posted in Infragistics forum.. and still couldnt get any replies... :(... It has been a day since :(

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem with the WebCombo control, and it seems to be a real compatibility issue. Infragistics response so far has been to update to the latest version of their controls, which is not an option to me right now:

[Infragistics forum's question about this issue](http://blogs.infragistics.com/forums/t/23315.aspx)